# How to be notified when a UITableViewController has reloaded its data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

First, why: I have a class called `AKTableViewController` that inherits from `UITableViewController` and most of my View Controllers inherit from that.

I'm tryingto make a Category to add a banner on the bottom of each screen, not scrolling with the content, so I add my banner as the `self.tableView.tableFooterView` and than I position it on `scrollViewDidScroll:`.

My problem is, when the data is reloaded the banner is sent back to the right position and I don't have any callback to properly position it.

So: How to be notified when an `UITableViewController` has reloaded its data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the delegate method for UITableView:

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if([indexPath row] == ((NSIndexPath*)[[tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] lastObject]).row){
        //Finished loading visible part of your table
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you're doing this seems convoluted. It sounds like you should be adding the banner as a separate view, not as a footer of the table view.

Comment: By adding the banner as a subview of the UITableViewController view it scrolled with the rest of the content. But it isn't pushed back to the footer of table view when it updates! While this fix my problem and that's the way I'll go it doesn't answer the quest from the title, so I'll choose the other answer.

Comment: The view of a table view controller is always a table view, you'll probably have to set up outside of that to remove your banner from the table view. It might be easier to use a regular `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` set up manually. Read this for more: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1371/how-to-integrate-iad-into-your-iphone-app

Comment: Using `UIViewController`s would mean rebuild a lot of screens, this really isn't convenient.